# Mat icon floating to the right of an input and not centered with typed text

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-6

I am trying to add an icon at the beginning of an input text box using angular material 6 icons, but it appears to be at the right and in the middle of the input and not centered with the typed text.

Here is my html script:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width" color="warn">
   <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
   <mat-icon matPrefix color="warn">user_group</mat-icon>
   <input matInput id="login-username" formControlName="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
          placeholder="username or email">
</mat-form-field>&nbsp;
```

And here is a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-abevly

I want the icon to be at the begining of the input and centered with typed text. I tried the `matSuffix` but it give the same result

Answer (score 4):

You can override the scss by switching to a center flex container (mat-form-field-flex) and removing padding on your input/select (mat-form-field-infix). See an example below:

```css
::ng-deep {
    mat-form-field {
        span[matprefix] {
            color: #828182;
            margin: 0.4rem;
        }

        div.mat-form-field-flex {
            align-items: center !important;
        }
        div.mat-form-field-infix {
            padding: 0 !important;
            border-top: 0 !important;
        }
        div.mat-form-field-wrapper {
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example uses Angular / Angular Material v5. In v5 the `MatPrefix` and `MatSuffix` directives' selectors were `mat-prefix` and `mat-suffix` only - `matPrefix` and `matSuffix` were not supported until v6. So you've used the wrong directive selector. Try:

```
<mat-icon mat-prefix color="warn">user_group</mat-icon>
```

Or switch to v6+.

Comment: `"@angular/material": "^6.3.3",`

Comment: My angular material version as shown in json file is v6

Comment: That's not what your Stackblitz example is using. And your Stackblitz example has a lot of other problems too - fix all of those and then see if it has the same alignment problem. It is _impossible_ to help you debug when what we are debugging is _different_ than your real life problem!